# How to combine wildcard search with range query within Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to combine wildcard with date range in Elasticsearch query but is not giving response based upon the wildcard search. It is returning response with items which have incorrect date range.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "hostName": "*abc*"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "requestDate": {
                    "gte": "2019-10-01T08:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The index mapping looks as below:

```
{
  "index_history": {
    "mappings": {
      "applications_datalake": {
        "properties": {
          "query": {
            "properties": {
              "term": {
                "properties": {
                  "server": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "index-data-type": {
        "properties": {
          "attributes": {
            "properties": {
              "wwnListForServer": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "hostName": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "requestDate": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "requestedBy": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `minimum_should_match` parameter,
Check this out : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html.
I think your query should looklike this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "hostName": "*abc*"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "requestDate": {
                    "gte": "2019-10-01T08:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match" : 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

From the documentation :

> You can use the minimum_should_match parameter to specify the number
>   or percentage of should clauses returned documents must match.
>
> If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or
>   filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value
>   is 0.

Comment: `{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
            }
        ],
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
    },
    "status": 400
}`

Answer (score 0):

According to your mappings, you have to call-out the fully qualified property for `hostName` and `requestDate` fields. Example:

```
"wildcard": {    
  "index-data-type.hostName": {
    "value": "..."
  }
}
```

Also, could also consider reducing your compound queries to just the main `bool` query, using the must clause, and apply a filter. Example:

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 20, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "index-data-type.hostName": {
              "value": "*abc*"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "index-data-type.requestDate": {
            "gte": "2019-10-01T08:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The filter context doesn't contribute to the `_score` yet it reduces your number of `hits`.

> **Warnining**:
>   Using the leading asterisk (*) on a wildcard query can have severe performance impacts to your queries.